# Python fresh import of external module (f2py) in new thread/process?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-import, python-multiprocessing, f2py

I use an external module created from a fortran module with f2py that contains a function I run repeatedly.

The underlying fortran (which I have no control over) is a bit finicky and sometimes develops a problem with keeping track of which arrays have already been allocated. When this happens, the next time I call the function there's a segmentation fault that crashes the whole python session.

However, I can diagnose when this problem arises, i.e. I know whether the next time I call the function it will crash. I want to know if there's a way I can do a "fresh" import of the f2py module at this point.

I'm hoping maybe there's a way an external module be loaded in a separate thread or process which can later be killed and started over again?

I'm imagining something like this:

```py
def funcwrapper():
    newprocess = start_new_process() #start a new process somehow
    newprocess.run('import f2py_module') #import f2py module into the new process
    newprocess.run('result = f2py_module.func()') #run the function
    result = newprocess.retrieve('result') #somehow get the result back into the main process
    newprocess.terminate() #kill the new process
    return result
```

I feel like this should be possible with MultiProcessing or Threading but I don't have much experience with those.